# Dexterity custom add forms trouble

Tags: python, plone, dexterity

I'm trying to set a different schema interface to a custom dexterity AddForm, but it is rendering the 'default' one, when I access the add form.

Here's my code:

*package.name.typename.py*

```
class IMyType(form.Schema):

    """ interface for mytype schema
    """
    title = schema.TextLine(
            title=_(u"Name"),
        )

    description = schema.Text(
            title=_(u"little description"),
        )

class IMyTypeAdd(IMyType):
    """ para formulario de add 
    """
    title = schema.TextLine(
            title=_(u"Name for custom addform"),
        )


class AddForm(dexterity.AddForm):
    grok.name('package.name.mytype')
    grok.context('IMyTypeAdd')
```

I can see that the add form interface is not used by seeing the title hint. 
Where is my error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the grok.context() statement. The context of an add form is not the type, it's the folder where the type is being added.

See http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/forms

Martin